# How to override an object without loosing the reference in angular 2/4

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I have the following case. I have two instances **originalMember** and **toSaveMember**, both of the same class **Person**.
How do i overide all the values from **toSaveMember** to **originalMember**, but still keep the same reference of originalMember?
This would be the equivalent of :

```
originalMember.name = toSaveMember.name;
originalMember.age = toSaveMember.age;
```

I dont want to use the solution above because i dont want to keep track of the new fields. I want something automatic. 
Anyone has any sugestions?

Thank you!

Comment: As I understand you want originalMember point to toSaveMember. So the only thing you have to do is originalMember = toSaveMember. If you add new properties to toSaveMember then originalMember  will have the same. But the question is then: Why do you have 2 variables if they always should have the same properties? Excuse me if I didn't understand your question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to set all properties from `toSaveMember` to `originalMember` while keeping separate object references for both:

```
Object.assign(originalMember, toSaveMember);
```

If your environment does not support ES6, then there is a [polyfill for `Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) which you can use for old versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the old but add something new.

```
private newMember(_name: string, _age: number){
  originalMember.name = toSaveMember.name;
  originalMember.age = toSaveMember.age;
  // or like @Saravana 
  originalMember = toSaveMember;
```

After this set your new name and age

```
  toSaveMember.name = _name;
  toSaveMember.age = _age;
}
```

Ofc don't forget to declare both objects on the component scope. (this.)

If you want to make a list of orginal **Members** make an array and push the values in `array[0]` orginal one member`array[1]` second member and so on.